# adding user to user groups based on user profile in LDAP using Liferay

Tags: java, ldap, hook, liferay

I would like to add user to groups created in liferay based on user profile i got from the LDAP using Liferay framework.

For example :

```
  If userX logging into liferay and if abc attribute set to Y i need to add him to UserGroup abc created in Liferay.

  If userY logged into liferay and if pqr attribute set to Y i need to add him to UserGroup pqr created in Liferay.

  to implement this feature what changes i need to do in liferay (i am using liferay 6.0.5) ?
```

Answer (score 1):

Please mention which liferay framework currently you have work on!

As per my knowledge, try to LDAP integration in Liferay 6.0.5. that import users/groups into Liferay via LDAP and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

LDAP import/export is not a standard extension point in Lifeary. Assuming Liferay 6+ there is the possibility of extending the specific service in a Hook plugin, but your case sounds like our recent issue and therefore you may need to create an EXT plugin and override the `com.liferay.portal.security.ldap.PortalLDAPImporterImpl` class with custom behaviour during the import process.